# I want automatized site grab to extend SEDE results, how far can I go?

Tags: discussion, scraping

I want to collect properties of deleted posts not disclosed by the SEDE, but available as 10k privilege. My method would be to generate a random sample of post Ids (by SEDE queries) and then using scripts to download the content (by logging in the site with my browser and then using my ordinary session cookie (`acct=...`) also in the script).

However, to my best knowledge, SE content rules at least dislike automatized site grabbing, so I do not want to do that.

However, I think, the purpose of these rules is to prevent (or to harden) data fishing or server overloads. My goal is to use the grabbed data in meta/chat discussions and I have absolutely no intent to grab anything without permission. But I have no way to prove it.

What can I do? Is it allowed or not? How far can I go?

Can I download 100 deleted question pages by a script? Can I do 10000? Or how much?

<sub>P.s. I never did such things until now and won't ever do if it is not allowed.</sub>

Comment: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: @Cerbrus I think, that is to motivate robo-clickers to think more. So it is for the the interactive usage. At the end, it also mentions the limits of the SE API. I wish to use the SE API only as a last resort, because as I read, it needs some registration and I dislike api keys and similars. But I will do it if the answer is that I can not grab.

Comment: Scraping will get you hard rate limited _real_ fast. The API is how you go about it. I also doubt SE is going to appreciate scraping. Not sure what they do about excessive and extensive scraping attempts (read: Not sure if employees get involved), but the automatic (hard) rate limit is going to slow you down substantially if you try.

Comment: If you want all of the data, you can grab the data dumps: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: @HereticMonkey Doesn't the data dump still exclude the exact same info about deleted posts as SEDE?

Comment: @HereticMonkey SE data dumps contain yet lesser data than the SEDE. The essence of this question is about the scrapping of data not available in the SEDE, but available as 10k+ privilege.

Comment: Technically you can scrape whatever you want and nobody can stop you. SE has implement rate limits, which prevent you from scraping this information quickly. An API is better but not all information is present there. I believe that as long as you do not abuse the resources and get rate-limited, it's ok to scrape the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus That is mostly about the interactive usage. At the end it mentions also the limits of the SE API. This question is not about the usage of the SE API, which requires various registrations and similar, it is about simple scrapping scripts by re-using the session cookie.

Comment: @Dharman 1) Technical possibility does not mean that it would be allowed. 2) The SE can stop me by suspending me.

Comment: Hey, I just gave you a link with what information there is available about rate limiting, as rate limiting is what you're asking about.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, but it probably does not apply in my case. The question is not about interactive, browser-based clicks and not about the SE API.

Comment: If it's not browser-based and it's not API based then how do you intend to scrape it?

Comment: Rate limits don't happen on the browser side. The server doesn't care if you're _browsing_ or _scraping_.

Comment: @Dharman As you can read in the question: by re-using the session cookie in my browser.

Comment: So that means you will use the same rate limits as mentioned in that article.

Comment: @Cerbrus Technical possibility does not mean that it would be allowed. The question is about, what is allowed.

Comment: Which is answered in the link I commented...

Comment: The server doesn't know that you are scraping the data. The only way to figure this out would be if your IP gets rate limited very often. That could mean that you are using some automation to visit SE pages. I doubt anyone would get suspended over that unless it would be some distributed DDoS attack.

Comment: I think you're not understanding that there's no difference between manual browsing, and scraping, as far as rate limits are concerned.

Comment: It doesn't really matter IMO. That link is the information you have. Whatever else you get here is speculation. You'd have to go to the actual owners of the site with that question to get any kind of truthful answer.

Comment: Here is related question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293750/are-sites-that-autonomously-scrape-stack-overflow-for-answers-to-programming-pro

Comment: @Dharman That looks useful, moment

Comment: And here is an official response in this matter on Meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow

Comment: Depending on what you want to do exactly, the dumps may provide some utility as you can fetch multiple dumps and assume that questions that were in an earlier one but not in a later one were deleted. This however excludes posts that were deleted quickly after posting.

Comment: @ErikA Please read the first sentence of the question again. The data dumps contain yet lesser information than the SEDE.

Comment: @peterh if you aren't reading the SEDE, how can you know that the posts weren't on SEDE?

Comment: @KevinB I do not understand your question. The SEDE contains a lot information about the deleted posts, but far from all (for example, no ViewCount neither closure reason).

Comment: similarly i don't understand yours, What purpose are you collecting this for? Knowing your goals, will immediately clear up any obstacles you may be running into that can be solved by using the correct technique.

Comment: They only block scrapers to protect themselves. If you're being very reasonable while scraping there's not going to be an issue. Scrape 100 posts an hour or so for a few days and you'll have several thousand without even raising an alarm.

Comment: @KevinB The purpose is to create stats using properties not available in the SEDE, but available as 10k+.

Comment: What kind of stats? be specific, we do have access to quite a few stats inherantly.

Comment: @Nick This is very likely, but not sure. If I step over some limits, it might be considered as a technical attack, even if my intent is (imho) pretty okay. Only that is sure what is officially allowed.

Comment: It won't be, not at a rate like that, you can view posts faster manually, and is far less than the scraping I did when compiling data on election voting.

Comment: @KevinB Here I wanted to create a closure reason distribution of the deleted and closed questions of the SO. But also earlier it happened, many times, that I wanted to do this, but I could not, because I was not sure that it is allowed. Beside the ClosureReason, also the ViewCount and the PostHistory for the deleted posts are imho very missing.

Comment: For example, i can tell you that in the past 30 days, on SO, 22.42% of the questions closed (7705 of them) were closed with "Needs details or clarity", and that 95 of those were reopened (1.23%), and 75 were edited. This information is already available to users with sufficient reputation.

Comment: @Nick: At that point, one might as well use the API instead of writing a scraper... Seems a lot easier.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but "mod" (10k+) tools are useful only for the last 30 days and give only aggregated access to a narrow set of the metadata.

Comment: That gets us back to, What are you collecting this data for? Why is 30 days of data not enough?

Comment: @Cerbrus Using the API is actually harder than scraping, but not far. Scraping can be done with ordinary bash+curl+xslt tools, API requires more complex automatization.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure, but the question is about scraping :p

Comment: @KevinB For everything.  [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/28448/peterh-please-delete-this-account?order_by=favorite) are my public SEDE queries, these help me a lot, but I need more.

Comment: I suspect peter wants some data to back up his claims [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415683/questions-about-latex-when-should-i-post-in-tex-latex-stack-exchange-vs-stack/415684?noredirect=1#comment893787_415684)

Comment: @Cerbrus That was only the last problem where I met this obstacle. I wanted to do this about a hundred times, but I could not. It seems I need to learn the SE API.

Comment: The SE API is not _that_ bad to use, and you can get a high daily quota by registering for a key

Comment: @Nick That will happen. Note the comments, saying essentially, "just scrape, here are the limits"... I do not want to know, what had happened if I hit these rate limits without the API.

Comment: @peterh My point is: you can combine data over time and see which posts have been deleted with the dump. They contain both less and more data since you have different timepoints, as stated in my comment...

Comment: @ErikA SEDE backups happen weekly, data dumps 3-monthly and they are huge. And most entity creation-deletion cycle happens much more quickly. Furthremore, I do not want to play with the SE, they have clear rules and I can get what I want while I follow their rules.

Comment: Then simply follow them. What's the problem? If you're hit by a rate limit, you will be limited. If you do it repeatedly or heavily enough, you'll lose access entirely.

Comment: @KevinB That I did not know, is it allowed, what I asked in the question. Please read the question.

Comment: I did read your question, and this has been said quite a few times now

Comment: @KevinB Read also the answer - SE blocks detected scrapers.

Comment: SE blocks scrapers that don't follow the rate limits. Otherwise, they aren't being detected. #logic

Comment: I'm getting conflicting information here. You say you can get what you want by following the rules, then you talk about being blocked as a scraper and overloading the server? Which one is it? If you use the API (no webscraping) and respect the rate limits and backoffs indicated by the API return values, you're not going to overload anything.

Comment: @ErikA Please read the question, what I asked. Please read the self-answer. Thank you very much your cooperation. Our discussion now ends.

Comment: @peterh Your question is vague and the self-answer downvoted. I'm trying to clarify the question. That's the point of these comments. Then we might be able to provide a good answer instead of the current one.

Comment: Asked already in 2015 on the uber-Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249893/how-many-requests-are-too-many  SE is keeping the exact criteria secret. It is too sensitive to be publicly known, specially when the sites are more often targeted by DDOS attacks these days.

Comment: @rene This is why I find the "just scrape, here are the limits" answers very, very dangerously bad. I find them so bad, and so obviously bad, that it is hard for me to imagine, how could the meta guys suggest these. Just a week ago, the site was unreachable for hours because an evolving ddos attack. People got network-wide ban, no one really knows, why they got it.

Comment: There is no other option then *just scrape, keep an eye on it and lower your scrape rate when you hit the IP ban*. You're of course free to keep banging your head against the meta wall until a formal answer is posted but we are afraid you might have hurt your head badly by the time that answer arrives, if ever. Instead we try to advice you to use common sense, and carefully scrape. Just today I ran a script that did a thing every 5 seconds. That was too much. My script stopped on the first error, I doubled the wait time to 10 seconds and it ran to completion. It is wat it is. We deal with it.

Comment: @rene Do you use the official API or some more direct automatization tool?

Comment: @peterh this was a custom build userscript  that ran in the browser (TamperMonkey as the scriptmanager) while logged in. I prefer the API and SEDE if I can but some stuff just can't be done otherwise.

Comment: Looks like OP overdid the scraping? Or why are they suspended until Jun 9?

Comment: @Lino Seems quite hard to believe after that "This is why I find the "just scrape, here are the limits" answers very, very dangerously bad" comment, doesn't it?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer:

- [SE blocks detected scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/259412).
- For automatized scraping, [the SE API is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/259412)

There are no clear limits, but doing this is very likely not the intended usage of the site.

Comment: I don't think it's your intention, but you have outright ignored much of the nuance of the conversation so far. Via your linked post (which is _really_ old, it hasn't substantially changed or been updated since _2009_, and thus may not be current), scrapers are blocked _when they don't play by the rules_. [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900), which has been linked several times now, documents all public rate limits for the site and API.

Comment: You seem to be looking for _permission_, someone to tell you "yes, go ahead". **You're not going to get that**, we simply don't have to authority to give you that. Scraping is a grey area. You'll _probably_ be fine, as long as you play nice by the rules that have been pointed out to you. Otherwise, whether this works or doesn't, whether you get rate limited or not, is completely up to you.

Comment: Other pertinent links: [Stack Exchange Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) | [Stack Exchange, Inc. API Terms of Use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use)

Comment: @zcoop98 I wrote about 3 times in the comment-chat above: one thing what is technically possible, and another what is allowed by the rules. This question asks for, what is allowed.

Comment: @zcoop98 These look useful resources to create a better answer, or improve this one. I will do that soon.

Comment: As has been said multiple times already, there is no difference between scraping and browsing, as far as rate limiting repercussions are concerned. _"What is allowed"_ is whatever the rate limits allow you to do... What _more_ are you asking? Your answers are in the linked questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, there is. Read the resources in the post and in the comments.